# NameError - name 'API' is not defined

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to do my homework which is crawling data from Twitter. But I always have this error. I tried everything to solve this but nothing works. This is my code:

```
import tweepy
import re
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from textblob import TextBlob
import nltk
import string

api_key = ""
api_secret_key = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

hasilSearch = API.search_tweets(q="vaksin", lang="en", count=50)
```

I'm getting an error: `NameError: name 'API' is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, `API` is undefined when you use it on the last line.
You need to use the instance of `tweepy.API` that you have initialized, `api`.
Python is case-sensitive.